# LibGDX - Turning TiledMapTiles into objects

Tags: java, libgdx, tilemap, tiled

I'm working on a harvest moon type game and I've already created lots of assets and have a working player. Now the issue is with the tile map. I use Tiled Map Editor to make the map and it renders  fine.

But if I want to be able to turn grass into farmland and plant seeds and such to allow crops to grow, how would I do that?

It would be rather simple using different classes like a `Farmland` and `Crop` class and make so that `Farmland` has a `Crop currentCrop;` attached to it.
But putting this together while still using a Tilemap editor seems rather difficult, since I don't actually get any Tile objects from the .tmx.

The way I could do it with Tiled is in my `MapManager` class I could have a

```
public void setCell(int x, int y, int type) {
    Cell cell = new Cell();
    switch(type) {
    case 0:
        cell.setTile(map.getTileSets().getTile(0);
    break;
}
```

etc.

But it feels like that would be a pain to keep track on how much thing have grown and so on and just feels like a clumsy system.

Am I going about this the right way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else wonders the same thing, instead of directly editing the tile map itself you just add objects above it.

For example have a `Farmland` class and when using let's say a `Hoe` you add a new object to an `ArrayList` which keeps track on all your placed objects in the game which could be anything. A tree, farmland, furniture etc.

Then to get the tile, add a method which checks if a temporary `Rectangle` collides with one of the `Rectangle`'s in your object list.